Is every bounded affine plane algebraic curve the union of closed curves?
I use the following definition for closed plane curves:
A set $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a closed plane curve if it is the image of a continuous function $\gamma: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$.
Under this definition, is it true that every bounded affine plane algebraic curve is the union of closed plane curves?

Do you know that algebraic curves are locally connected?

No. I have not studied algebraic geometry. I am studying complex analysis, and while exploring how complex polynomials transform the complex plane, I started wondering if this fact holds.

I see. The answer to your question is positive but proofs are beyond of what you currently know. Incidentally, your definition of a curve is inappropriate for most purposes. For bounded real algebraic curves it is true that they are homeomorphic to finite graphs of even valence. I can suggest a book where this is proven but it is unlikely you are ready for this material.

@MoisheKohan please do. I would like to have it as a reference in the future.

Here is a reference that you might read one day if you are interested in this staff:
Akbulut, Selman; King, Henry, Topology of real algebraic sets, Mathematical Sciences Research Institute Publications. 25. New York: Springer-Verlag. x, 249 p. (1992). ZBL0808.14045.
One consequence is that every compact real-algebraic curve is homeomorphic to a finite graph of even valence. Every such graph is Eulerian, hence, can be represented as a union of singletons (isolated vertices) and embedded cycles (simple loops).

Thank you sir!!
